# Blender bevel mitering struggling with very sharp corners

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bevel, tools

Blender's bevel tool (specifically in my case, the modifier) works pretty well and is extremely useful, however I think I've found a limitation of it. If anyone knows how to solve this problem, I would really appreciate the help!

When beveling a very sharp corner like the mesh in the image below, the bevel tool seems to really struggle.

[image: The object in question]

[image: The object post bevel]

As you can see, the sharp angle causes the connection between the edges to freak out. I've tried messing around with all of the bevel settings, I've tried also beveling the edge that connects both of these edges at the top, beveling the vertex that connects at the top and then beveling the edges separately, but blender really just seems to struggle here.

I recreated the mesh in maya just to see what it would do, and I got this result:

[image: A similar setup in maya]

Maya seems to handle the operation just fine, and I believe it's due to it's Auto Mitering option in the bevel settings. When I turn it off, the mesh seems to have a similar issue to the one I'm getting in blender. Blender has mitering options as well, but no combination of them that I can find fixes this issue. Does anybody know what to do here? Or is this just a bug that needs to be reported?

Comment: You need to include the edge that's at the V going from the front to the back.

Comment: Unfortunately no, this does not help. It doesn’t fix the deformation and it also messes up the mesh even more :(

Comment: Can you add your blend file to your question? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: Here's an example of the problem in question: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=wQdKdgbO" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/wQdKdgbO/)

Comment: I'm going with the idea that you've found a bug in the bevel code.  Maybe submit this last file as a bug report?

Comment: was my thinking too, will do